# c# - Request.Files is always empty after UploadFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

I'm trying to upload a file from a windows form c# client application to an ASP.NET C# application.
Actually i have this code running in the client application:

```
WebClient uploader = new WebClient();
string UploadFilePath = "<filepath>";
string uploadWebUrl = "http://localhost:51037/(S(044401gmyxhg3uz01ulngfdp))/upload.aspx";
byte[] responseArray = uploader.UploadFile(uploadWebUrl, UploadFilePath);
```

And this is upload.aspx page

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web"%>

<Script language="C#" runat=server>
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs("~/Download/"+file.FileName);
    }   
}

</Script>
<html>
<body>
<p> Upload complete.  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

the point is that, actually, "Request.Files" is an empty string array and i don't get why

Comment: upload.aspx secure page or non secure page?

Comment: It is actually on a pre-existing project but, for what i know (the upload.aspx page is totally new and created by me but i'm not an expert of asp.net) the  page should be non secure

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add "POST" to your upload file command:

```
byte[] responseArray = uploader.UploadFile(uploadWebUrl, "POST", UploadFilePath);
```

Here is Microsoft's documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329790(v=vs.71).aspx

In it, here is the method signature for UploadFile:

```
public byte[] UploadFile(
 string address,
 string method,
 string fileName
);
```

Comment: In order to help you, people are going to need more feedback than that.  You should describe what is happening, including any error messages that you get, etc.